# Variables are not recognized on Master partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, master-pages

Its an old project, .Net 3.5, which I'm now trying to update to 4.5.
I'm trying to use Master Pages:

NZHos3ColNew.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NZHos3ColNew.master.cs" Inherits="NZJobFinder.NZTemplateMasterPage" %>
```

NZHos3ColNew.master.cs

```
namespace NZJobFinder {
public partial class NZTemplateMasterPage: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        litLoginStyle.Text = "style='height:10px;padding-top:5px;width:70px;left:890px;top:10px;'";
```

But, when building, I get:

```
Error   24  The name 'litLoginStyle' does not exist in the current context  C:\nzjobfinder\App_Master\NZHos3ColNew.master.cs    25  21  nzjobfinder
```

Any helps here? What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like your .master file and its code-behind got disconnected in the shuffle somehow. Without seeing your actual project, it might be hard to suggest a specific solution. Of course, you should make sure `litLoginStyle` is actually defined somewhere.

Comment: Well, the NZHos3ColNew.master has it:
    <div id="LoginBK" <asp:Literal id="litLoginStyle" Text="" runat="server" />></div>
I was thinking that the compiler sees this definition on the page and adds the variable to the parent class, isn't it like that? Should I define it on my NZHos3ColNew.master.cs ?

Comment: I'm far from an expert in ASP.NET. But generally the way these things work is that in your project file, the non-C# file is linked to the C# file in a way that allows the build process to generate the appropriate C# to go with your code-behind. From your description, it sounds like that connection got lost somehow (the `CodeFile` attribute in the .master file notwithstanding). How are you upgrading the project? Are you opening the older project in a newer version of Visual Studio? Or trying to effect the upgrade by hand?

Comment: Now, I have added some classes using these missing attributes, and the error has started to be:
Error 24 Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl). C:\nzjobfinder\App_Master\NZHos3ColNew.master.cs 15 33 nzjobfinder